# How to read query parameters in spray?

Tags: scala, http, get, spray

I want to get parameters such as  String and integer in spray,for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/nexus?taskId=1&operatorId=3&version=10&day=12&hour=7&minute=3
```

I use code:

```
path("nexus"){
              get {
                 parameters('taskId.as[Int], 'operatorId.as[Int],'version.as[Int],'day.as[Int],'hour.as[Int]    ,'minute.as[Int])
                  {  (taskId,operatorId,version,day,hour,minute) =>
                    complete{s"$taskId"}
                     }       
                 }
```

I use this code to test:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/nexus?taskId=1&operatorId=3&version=10&day=12&hour=7&minute=3
```

But it's lead to this error:

```
Request is missing required query parameter 'operatorId'
```

and operatorId really exist!

I don't know How to do!

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. Just wrap the URL with double quotes:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/nexus?taskId=1&operatorId=3&version=10&day=12&hour=7&minute=3"
```